# Does NVDEC 8.0 decoding sdk support mapping decoded surfaces to D3D11 textures?

Tags: video, cuda, directx-11, nvenc

I'm developing a decoder, based on NVDEC 8.0 API to process H264 streaming. However, I stumbled upon an inability to figure out if and how I can render decoded frames to D3D11 surfaces without copying frames back to main memory. I went over the cudaDecodeD3D9 code sample, provided with SDK, but it ultimately uses D3D9 technology but I'm bound to use existing D3D11Device instance, provided from outside rendering component. Is it possible to accomplish this without involving D3D9 to D3D11 interop?

Answer (score 1):

Well, shortly after I posted the question, I got a response from NVIDIA support, that guided me to where i can download more resent samples pack, including D3D11 decoding support. Here it is:

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk#Download